# syntax error, unexpected T_end, expecting T_the

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm new to OZ Mozart, I'm trying to write a triangular sequence but the programming won't work.

```
declare
fun {Sequence N R}
   fun {Help I}
      if I < N
     sum = {Int.toFloat(N*(N+1)/2.0)}
     %I + 1
     case R of nil then {Append [sum] nil}
     [] H|T then sum|H|T
     end
     I+1
      end
   end
in
   {Help 0}
end

declare
{Browse {Sequence 5 nil}}
```

If there anything wrong with my programming?
It shows error like:

```
%*************************** parse error ************************
%**
%** syntax error, unexpected T_end, expecting T_then
%**
%** in file "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/test (2).oz", line 11, column 6
%** ------------------ rejected (1 error)
```

Any idea about that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood what a triangular sequence is, the followinf is a simple implementation. But first of all your error means that you have to use the `then` keyword in the `if` statement.
Type conversion from float to int is not necessary as every number multiplied by its successor gives an odd number. This simplify the variable management.
Here's what I suggest:

```
declare

fun {Sequence N}
   local X in
     if N>0 then
      X = (N*(N+1) div 2)
      X|{Sequence N-1}
     else nil
     end
    end
 end

{Browse {Sequence 5}}
```

This is just an example, it gives a triangular sequence in reverse order, you can easily fix it according to your desire.